# Pytorch Functions Consolidation

Tags: c++, pytorch

I am trying to consolidate torch::where and torch::greater into a single function. I have bypass the binary output from torch::where to store the indexes into a vector object; however, the performance is not efficient compared to where and greater functions. I have included my solution:

std::vector  idxs;

```
        for(int x = 0; x < tensor.numel(); x++){
                    if (tensor[x].item<float>() > threshold)
                                        idxs.push_back(x);
                                
        }
```

Is there a more optimized solution to pytorch's where and greater functions?

Comment: You can pre-allocate your `idxs` vector.

Comment: `torch::where` and `torch::greater` are mask-type, not index. What exactly you want, why `torch.where(x > threshold, x, y)` bad?

Comment: @AlexeyBirckov, so x will be a tensor of indexes ? and, not the binary ?